# What stock(s) denote the unofficial start of "earnings season"?

Tags: stocks, investing, options, corporate-earnings

I have heard AA (Alcoa Corporation) and JPM (JP Morgan Chase) mark the start of "earnings season" is there any other consensus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a long time, traders and investors used the earnings date of Alcoa as a  proxy for the earnings season because it was the first DJIA component and first major industrial player to report.  Now, it's no longer a DJIA component.

These days, there are earnings reports almost  every day of the week with Friday being an occasional exception.  There are a  couple  dozen reporting this week and it's not even "earnings season" yet.  Dozens more will report before AA does and some notable names in that group are ABT, C, COST, GWW, JNJ, JPM, NFLX, PEP, WBA, WFC.  So I don't think that AA is relevant any longer nor is there any particular consensus starting date.

What will happen is a week by week increase in reporting companies culminating at about 400 per day later next month.